# Numpy: placing values into an 1-of-n array based on indices in another array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose we had two arrays: some values, e.g. `array([1.2, 1.4, 1.6])`, and some indices (let's say, `array([0, 2, 1])`) Our output is expected to be the values put into a bigger array, "addressed" by the indices, so we would get

```
array([[ 1.2,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1.4],
       [ 0. ,  1.6,  0. ]])
```

Is there a way to do this without loops, in a nice, fast way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
a = zeros((3,3))
b = array([0, 2, 1])
vals = array([1.2, 1.4, 1.6])
```

You just need to index it (with the help of `arange` or `r_`):

```
>>> a[r_[:len(b)], b] = vals


array([[ 1.2,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1.4],
       [ 0. ,  1.6,  0. ]])
```

Comment: As an alternative: `a[zip(*enumerate(b))]=vals`

Answer (score 0):

How do we modify this for higher dimensions? For example, a is a 5x4x3 array and b and vals are 5x4 arrays. 
then How do we modify the statement a[r_[:len(b)],b] = vals ?